# How to execute a command when an entity is a certain number of blocks away from another entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a gun in vanilla Minecraft and I need it so when an armor stand is within a certain amount of blocks away from another entity, it performs a command.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: We don't make commands for people here on Arqade unfortunately. Try making something yourself, and then ask us why it doesn't work, or something along those lines.

Comment: I would recommend checking out this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHYAYMSbpcvulT34yXXN6SjTgpi0bOgka

Comment: As a correction, @user1337, many people have received help on minecraft commands, especially when asking "how to" or "whats wrong with my" questions

Comment: @FungusKing From what I've seen and was told, "Why doesn't this cmd work?" is fine, but "How do I do X?" isn't. If what you say is true, then by all means.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an execute command to use the range selectors relative to one of the entities:

```
/execute @e[name=ENTITY1] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[name=ENTITY2,r=X,rm=X] ~ ~ ~ /COMMAND
```

Replace `name=ENTITY2` with however you're identifying the entity you want to perform the command, `name=ENTITY1` with however you're identifying the other entity, `COMMAND` with whatever command you want to run, and `r=X,rm=X` with the range you want it to run at (`rm` is the minimum, so should be smaller than or equal to `r`).

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at @e[name=ENTITY1] at @e[name=ENTITY2,distance=X..Y] run COMMAND` (where `X` is the minimum and `Y` is the maximum.